# Highlight nodes covered by XPath

Tags: java, xpath, html-parsing, htmlunit

I want to highlight nodes covered by a given XPath in an HTML page source.

I looked to in HtmlUnit, could not find any thing in API.

At present, I am thinking of doing it following way:

1. Get XPath and Get Page-source.
2. Break XPath to smaller chunks and store them in Xpath_chunk[].
3. Apply chunk from Xpath_chunk[] starting from 0.
4. Update css property of each node found by each chunk(any change which distinguishes the text).
5. Now add get next chunk and concate it with current.
6. Go to Step 3.

In this way, I will visit all nodes covered by Xpath. With some more changes I can remove those elements which were unnecessarily highlighted.

This is too complicated. Is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

I recently made a rudimentary implementation using JavaFX's WebEngine + WebView. Register a DOM listener to all the nodes of the loaded website's Document, so you can listen to clicks on those Nodes. When clicking, change the style of the Node and add some CSS. WebView will reflect the changes and render the page correctly.

The Document that WebEngine returns can also be accessed using XPath (it's a w3d document), so you can traverse it and modify all the nodes you encounter (or use the Node that is the furthest down, then travel upwards using getParent(), and modify each parent as well).

Comment: I want to create something like Firebug but not as a Firefox plugin. I want to run it as web application.

Comment: Well, it's a lot of code, I don't know if I can easily create a selection that shows what it's about. Anyway, in the end JavaFX's WebEngine had some fundamental flaws (you cannot synchronously load webpages to retrieve their dom with webengine), so I chose to remake the project in GWT and work straight in a webpage.

Generally: 
1) a RPC service downloads a webpage on the server side
2) that webpage is loaded in a HTMLPanel
3) DOMlisteners make sure we can listen to selections of Element's
4) changing the style of an element is easy to do